# WebView2 rendering in wrong place when used on Outlook VSTO panel on mixed DPI screens

Tags: outlook, ms-office, webview2

I'm trying to use WebView2 for rendering the content in Outlook VSTO Custom Pane.

I'm struggling with the issue when my plugin is used in a system with multiple monitors which have different scaling / DPI settings. The content is rendered at random place outside the TaskPane. To be precise - this is only rendering issue, as all hit tests seems to be working in proper places.

The example:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/storage/attachments/159888-outlook-dpi-issue.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKlRr.png)

The exact issue was reported to edge / webview team by other people as well, but it seems the issue is on Office side. Here is the thread for the reference:
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/820

Hopefully perhaps is there any workaround? This is a major showstopper for me and our clients.

I'm using Win10 21H2, .Net framework 4.6.2, Outlook version 2102, webview 1.0.1054.31, edge 96.0.1054.62

Comment: It seems you need to open a support case with Microsoft. The page you are referring to states the following - `The "popping out while dragging" is a bug on Office that they are still investigating.`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in MS Office. For a workaround, use Chromium with the `--disable-gpu-compositing` switch.

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. I checked using Process Explorer that msedge process was indeed created with desired switch but the issue is still there. I also tried  `--disable-gpu` but no success either.

Comment: @TomoP Hi, did you get any breakthrough with this issue? We have same issue and along with that freezing (Details & Steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840766/vsto-outlook-plugin-custom-task-pane-webview2-fails-to-load-with-different-moni). If anything helped with your issue  then please share. Thanks