# VSTO Outlook Plugin: Custom task pane WebView2 fails to load with different monitor scaling (Known issue) | Any workaround from code

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, webview2

With outlook plugin Custom Task pane and WebView2 control it's a known issue that the form gets misplaced when you load the form on different monitor scaling. This can generally happen when you work on multiple screens with different resolution or you work from office and then login back from home with different size of monitor.
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/820

Along with this behaviour, I see one more issue where meeting / email windows gets into freezing state as soon as I try to open up form, very random but associated with same scaling issue. That time form is completely in grey state but still control loads fine behind the scene as per the WebView2 console logs.

Added steps [7th August 2023]

1. Keep your monitor scaling to 100% (recommended option)
2. Open outlook
3. Change monitor scaling to 125% [Don't open meeting / email window]
4. Open new meeting / email window and click on your plugin ribbon button
   Form will be in grey state and it gets into freezing as well. You have to close out that particular window from the task bar.

This issue is with only WebView2 control but with IE based WebBrowser this issue is not there but that's something too old for latest UI frameworks.

For these there are two workarounds mentioned

1. Configure office for optimize for compatibility - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-support-for-high-definition-displays-6720ca0e-be59-41f6-b629-1369f549279d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us [This works but not always and freezing issue still appears with this configuration as well but frequency is less]
2. Handle DPI Scaling - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/ddpi/handle-high-dpi-and-dpi-scaling-in-your-office-solution#office-compatibility

In this link it's mentioned *"Because custom task panes are child windows, they cannot receive DPI notifications. If they are drawing incorrectly, the user will need to use Office DPI compatibility mode"*
Does that mean this solution cannot work for custom task pane ?

However, as per this Add-in express article they do support it - https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/add-in-express-multiple-dpi-monitors/

So I want to understand if it's really feasible option ? and if yes then is there any sample anyone can share.

Is anyone really using VSTO plugin custom task pane with WebView2 control for production users with all these issues ?

Thank you.

Comment: Any idea if "CoreWebView2Controller.RasterizationScale" can help with this issue ? if yes any example and more details would be appreciated. Thanks